# Export 3D data DXF file

Tags: qgis, data, 3d, export, dxf

I'm trying to export a DXF file from QGIS 1.8.0 Lisboa and can not have a 3D file in AutoCAD or Microstation. It results always in 2D file.

How can I export height data from a shapefile in QGIS?

Comment: Hi Marques! Did you find the solution? I am also looking for the solution.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to get a 3D DXF from a SHP (SHPfile generated from DTM with 
Qgis-Processing-Tools-GDAL/OGR Extraction-Contour), you must:

1) have column with Z values into Table attributes of SHP.
2) open "OSGeo4W Shell Commands" if you have Windows OS.
3) write into shell for example:

ogr2ogr -f "dxf" d:\Temp\3Doutput.dxf d:\Temp\contour.shp -zfield ELEV

the syntax is as follows:
ogr2ogr -f "DXF" {outFile} {inFile} -zfield {ColumnWithZValue}

If an error appear, ignore it, go to the folder that contain the output file and if you find a file named "3Doutput" without extension (in this example), rename it as "3Doutput.dxf", then you will can open it with AutoCAD or other software.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it from within QGIS itself but you can do it this way:

http://nathanw.net/2011/05/05/3d-dxf-using-ogr/

```
ogr2ogr -f "DXF" {outFile} {inFile} -zfield {ColumnWithZValue}
```

Comment: Didn't work, it says it's not a recognized command. Any other tip? Thank you for your prompt response

Comment: You will need to run it using the OSGeo4W shell (if your on windows that is)

Comment: C:\>ogr2ogr -f "DXF" E:\tsteQgis\processameto\mapset\CN3D_vf E:\tsteQgis\process
ameto\mapset\CN.shp -zfield CONTOUR
ERROR 1: DXF layer does not support arbitrary field creation, field 'ID' not cre
ated.
ERROR 1: DXF layer does not support arbitrary field creation, field 'ELEV' not c
reated.

C:\>ogr2ogr -f "DXF" E:\tsteQgis\processameto\mapset\CN3D_vf1 E:\tsteQgis\proces
sameto\mapset\CN.shp -zfield ELEV
ERROR 1: DXF layer does not support arbitrary field creation, field 'ID' not cre
ated.
ERROR 1: DXF layer does not support arbitrary field creation, field 'ELEV' not c
reated.

Comment: That is the error that i got using the tip you gave me! I'm running out of solutions to overcome this problem. You know any other solution? Thank you so much!

Comment: Does it still make the dxf file though. DXFs don't have fields so that is a warning your get not really a error.

Comment: Yes, it produces the dxf file however the same problem persists for me, not having a dxf file with altimetric info, just a 2D file. Is there any other way to overcome this?

Comment: Simple answer is no.  The ogr driver does not support writing attribute information.  http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_dxf.html

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS 3.2.3, it's possible, without using GDAL.

When generating the contours, just check the "Produce 3D Vector" in the "Advanced Parameters".

After that, just export the layer with "Save As". The option "Include Z dimension" will be checked already.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We export our files as a xyz text file for export into 12D for one of our contractors, which may also work if you are having problems, I haven't tried it since we don't have autocad or 12D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps, but I used ogr2ogr and converted from shp to shp adding the -zfield argument and was able to reference the shp into microstation as contours with elevations.

ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" {outFile.shp} {inFile.shp} -zfield {ColumnWithZValue}

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me. I used QGIS to produce a shp file from a geotiff from https://data.linz.govt.nz

Then opened GDAL and put as per Nathan W above:

```
ogr2ogr -f "dxf" C:\0GeoOUT\kane4.dxf C:\0GeoIN\contour.shp -zfield ELEV
```

So I could understand it better on my system I set up input and output folders. I avoided spaces or periods in paths as I had failure (dxf write failure) when they existed.

I did get these errors (but dxf works fine):

```
    ERROR 4: Unable to open C:\0GeoOUT\kane4.dxf to obtain file list.
    ERROR 1: DXF layer does not support arbitrary field creation, field 'ID' not created.
    ERROR 1: DXF layer does not support arbitrary field creation, field 'ELEV' not created.
```

Answer (score 0):

In QGIS 2.18.14 the `save as` option has a 
`datasource` creation field where the  -zfield {ColumnWithZValue} could be written.
I did not tested yet, but it looks to be the apporach within QGIS.

The box with `Include z-dimension` I guess works only with object with that dimension, but not with shape files.

[image: menu save as]