# How to Export to DXF and retain elevations of contours using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, export, dxf

I have shape files for a whole county, and have created a base map in Qgis. What I do for my projects is zoom into the area of interest then export to dxf. The same procedure was used when I used Arcgis, however I had to go into the features and create a new feature called ELEVATION and copy the z values from the county ELEV into the newly created ELEVATION. I have tried this in Qgis but I am still not getting the contours on an elevation in cad. I have read some post about entering a code into OSGeo4WShell but the problem I have with that is my contour shape file is for a whole county and is way too big to bring into cad. I also keep getting errors so What options do I have?

Answer (score 2):

This question was answered here: [Export 3D data DXF file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/56915/export-3d-data-dxf-file)

See this command:

```
ogr2ogr -f "DXF" {outFile} {inFile} -zfield {ColumnWithZValue}
```

Comment: I read that as well as others and did not get a solution. Does the "infile need to be .shx"? Keep getting "FAILURE: Unable to open datasource g:\Jobs\Jobs'. Is there clear directions for a novice like me anywhere?

Comment: @ChristopherDombeck you can use the doc of ogr2ogr for more information, but this is the way that you need. You select a layer of interest, and save as a shp, after use it to transform in dxf file.